# Tool unzip is missing, buildozer, kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I am new to kivy, and try to build an app for android using kivy.

When i was creating an apk for the app

```
buildozer android debug
```

with log_level=2
it shows:

```
Tool unzip is missing
Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "kivytut"

Buildozer failed to execute the last command
The error might be hidden in the log above this error
Please read the full log, and search for it before
raising an issue with buildozer itself.
In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I'm unable to find any tool called upzip for buidozer(python-for-android) on the internet.

Help.

Answer (score 1):

install unzip using:

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

moreover following are the tools that must be installed:

```
git
ant
python2
cython (can be installed via pip)
a Java JDK (e.g. openjdk-7)
zlib (including 32 bit)
libncurses (including 32 bit)
unzip
virtualenv (can be installed via pip)
ccache (optional)
```

These are several dependencies for python-for-android